# How to know what view is in the same context than other

Tags: android, android-webview, android-context

I have a class where I have a List with three WebView from different Activities

```
public class Class {


private List<WebView> webViews;

    .
    .
    .

public void bindOnClickEvent(ActionMethod aMethod, View control){
        control.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //Here I need know which webview in webViews is in the same context that View control

            //webView.loadUrl("javascript:myJSFunction(\'"+s+"\');");                               
        }
    });
}
}
```

I need use inside of the method onClick(View v) the webView (that i can found in the List "webViews") which is in the same context that the parameter View v.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Different Activities on the same screen?? (how do you do that?) Or different Fragments? You code snippet doesn't show the interesting parts.

Comment: I have three activities in three differents classes. When i start an activity i register its webview in the class that i have wrote above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`View` has a method `getContext()`. You should be able to compare the contexts to determine which `View`s belong to which `Activity`s.

Comment: Thanks! I am going to prove it!